# How to open file in diff mode on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I opened this diff changes from the right hand side 'Git Changes' sidebar tab on Visual Studio. I'm in awe by how hard to navigate around this code editor. I'm a long time user Visual Studio Code, and this definitely stark cosmos away from how good vscode is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfvjV.png)

I tried looking everywhere, I just wanted to go to the said file and edit it there

Comment: As sahinbey52 wrote on reddit in his post [Things that I hate about VS](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/qcsq2c/things_that_i_hate_about_vs/):  "2. Git extension sucks when we compare with VS Code. The comparison shows the deleted lines on the left side and added lines on the right side. In VS Code, they are together, easy to see." I guess you're not alone there.